# Kontroverse Fragen oder Antworten suchen

Tags: support, feature-request

Gibt es eine Möglichkeit, gezielt Fragen oder Antworten zu suchen, die besonders kontrovers bewertet wurden?

Wenn ich Beiträge finden möchte, die mindestens fünf (oder eine signifikante Anzahl) negative Bewertungen haben, aber auch so viele positive, dass sie insgesamt nicht (oder nicht stark) negativ bewertet sind:
Wie stelle ich das an?

Eine Sortierung nach *votes* hilft nicht, da dann die positiven und negativen Bewertungen aufgerechnet werden.

Answer (score 3):

Wir haben ein mächtige [Datensuchmaschine](http://data.stackexchange.com/) an der Hand, mit der wir allerhand selbstgestrickte Suchen programmieren können.

Zum Glück muss man aber das Rad meist nicht neu erfinden, denn zu allen möglichen Anfragen gibt es schon fertige Scripte, oder Scripte, die wir nur ein bisschen anpassen müssen.

Zu deiner Frage habe ich folgendes gefunden:

- [Most controversial posts on the site](http://data.stackexchange.com/german/query/882964/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site)

  *Das Skript sucht nach allen Posts, die mindestens halb soviele Downvotes wie Upvotes haben und gibt diese sortiert nach Upvotes aus.*

Comment: Ich kannte den Data Explorer nicht einmal

Comment: Ich kann den leider nicht programmieren :(